# Why does using curl or wget from terminal not register as a pageview on launchrock

Tags: curl, wget

When I run the command

```
curl example.com
```

I get this response:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://signup.example.com/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

. . where signup.example.com is a page hosted by launchrock.  However, when I look at the launchrock insights page, it is not registering an additional pageview.  Why is this?

It also does not register an additional pageview when I run:

```
wget example.com
```

Follow up in response to comment from @Mike Christensen:

When I run

```
curl -i -L example.com
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Mon, 19 Dec 2011 16:19:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://signup.example.com/
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Runtime: 0.000724
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Content-Length: 96
X-Varnish: 1781129531
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.4
Date: Mon, 19 Dec 2011 16:19:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14
Content-Length: 2461
```

But still no additional pageview on launchrock's insights page.

Second update:

After inspecting the html on the signup.example.com which is hosted by launchrock, I found the following:

```
try{  

  var lrPageTracker = _gat._getTracker("XX-XXXXXXXX-X");
  lrPageTracker._setDomainName("signup.example.com");
  lrPageTracker._trackPageview();

      }catch(err){

}
```

I suspect this is what launchrock is using to track pageviews.  How could I use a terminal command to get this to register?

Comment: Maybe try `curl -L example.com` to follow re-directs?  Otherwise, please post the full HTTP headers (`-i`) so we can see what's being returned.

Comment: Ah - I guess the next step would be to figure out how Launchrock records a page view.  Does the client have to execute some Javascript?  Does it embed a 1x1 pixel GIF file somewhere?

Comment: I think you're probably right but I don't know the answers to your questions or how to find out.

Comment: If you want, you can post the full HTML somewhere (`jsfiddle` or `pastie.org`) and I can look at it.

Comment: Well you can't run Javascript from curl - What you'll need to do is trace the HTTP activity the script is performing (using something like Fiddler) and then figure out how to mimic that on the command line.

Comment: Little more work than I have time for at the moment, but thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Yup - It could end up being totally non-trivial if the script has all sorts of logic and does complicated `POST` commands.  If you ever do get around to this, check out `jMeter` - it does this sort of thing pretty well and can be run from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used LaunchRock, but if it's anything like Clicky or Google Analytics, it most likely embeds some Javascript in the page to track user statistics and page views.  This allows it to record things like what browser they're using, screen sizes, language settings, region, etc.

Sometimes these services also support browsers with no Javascript support by embedding a small, 1x1 pixel GIF image on the page somewhere that points to their own server with a URL parameter indicating the client ID.

I'd analyze the page HTML and try to figure out what HTML Launcrock is embedding into your page so you can reverse engineer exactly how a page view is recorded.  If you're still stuck, I'd post on the LaunchRock forums (if there are any) or email their support.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not loading pages from `signup.example.com` - you load the default page from `example.com` which is probably a different server; different servers can't (for security and other reasons) see each other access logs.

Try `wget signup.example.com`

If that does register, you have in fact two different servers (one which handles logins and another that just serves pages).

Comment: Running wget signup.example.com does not register as a pageview either.  I suspect, as Mike Christensen suggests in his comments that it might be how launchrock records a pageview.